# Module.exports in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, module.exports

What is **different** between `module.exports = testMethod ;` and `module.exports = { testMethod } ;` Because when I am using `module.exports = testMethod ;` it is throwing error as below.
**Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]**
But I am okay with `module.exports = { testMethod } ;`

Whole codes are

```
const testMethod = asyncErrorWrapper(async (req, res, next) => {
  const information = req.body;

  const question = await Question.create({
    title: information.title,
    content: information.content,
    user: req.user.id,
  });

  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    data: question,
  });
});

module.exports = { testMethod };
```

Comment: The first exports `testMethod` whatever that is, and the second exports an object with a property `testMethod` whose value is `testMethod`. --- This may have little to do with the error. May you share a [mcve]?

Comment: One uses object shorthand syntax to wrap it in an object and one doesn't.

Comment: this is all normal js syntax, and not any magic special something. It's simply a [shorthand property definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Property_definitions).

Comment: What's the difference between a = 1; b = a and a = 1; b = { a } ?

Comment: I see , the point is the one export is an object the other is not. Thanks...

Comment: @WiktorZychla a = 1; b = a and a = 1; b = { a } ? I was thinking b = {a} and b =a are same ... Can you explain a little more ? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

From VSCode, change between the ES5 or ES6 version to Js can take you on a bad way.
So, be carreful, i have the same problem recently, and after refactoring by use on ES6 `module.exports = router` to the end of some Js file (Node project using express) it was done.

Strange for me, on Cloud9 on Aws i have no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Both are worked to export your module to outside function. But when you are using any callback function with

```
module.exports = somectrl
```

then it will fail but

```
module.exports = { somectrl }
```

because when you create an object, it actually instanciate it but when you pass a ref function/ const function name then it will behave as a existing function which does not work right.

you can do something like this to work,

```
module.exports = somectrl()
```

or

```
module.exports = new somectrl()
```